# SQL Server script, overwrite case sensivity at database level

Tags: sql-server

My ASP.NET application is developed with a SQL Server database with a case insensitive collation. The inline SQL scripts sometimes use variables and CTEs. In a case insensitive server, the app works perfectly fine, even if sometimes the variable names mismatch capitalization.

Recently the database team migrated our database to a different server that IS case sensitive, and some of the code path started failing.

The database team can not change the server collation because an existing database requires that particular collation. Is there a way for me to set a flag or something at connection property, or anywhere, to treat the script as case insensitive? There are more than 50 data access calls, so it would be tiresome for me to check each SQL block to ensure capitalization.

Any help?

Comment: I believe you should be able to host a database using case insensitive collation on a sql server instance where the default is case sensitive collation as long as you create the database correctly. During the migration: Was the database restored or recreated from schema and then data population?

Answer (score 1):

You can set your database to be a [Partially Contained Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/contained-databases?view=sql-server-2017), which will allow you to use [Contained Database Collations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/contained-database-collations?view=sql-server-2017), which completely isolate you from the instance collation, and even allow you to use a case-sensitive collation for your data, without having a case-sensitive collation for your catalog, or code.